# postfix erro: mail transport unavailable

Tags: postfix, dovecot, amavis

I install postfix, dovecot, Amavisd, Spamassassin and clamav on FreeBSD 11.
I can not receive mail and the log is:

```
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 postfix/smtpd[1309]: connect from t7.example.com[192.x.x.x]
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 postfix/smtpd[1309]: 34D37115F3A: client=t7.example.com[192.x.x.x]
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 postfix/cleanup[1290]: 34D37115F3A: message-id=<20170919113016.34D37115F3A@t7.example.com>
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 postfix/qmgr[1190]: 34D37115F3A: from=<user1@example.com>, size=466, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 spamd[580]: spamd: connection from localhost [::1]:27779 to port 783, fd 5 
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 spamd[580]: spamd: setuid to spamd succeeded 
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 spamd[580]: spamd: processing message <20170919113016.34D37115F3A@t7.example.com> for spamd:58 
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 postfix/smtpd[1309]: disconnect from t7.example.com[192.x.x.x] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 spamd[580]: spamd: clean message (-1.0/5.0) for  spamd:58 in 0.2 seconds, 488 bytes. 
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 spamd[580]: spamd: result: . -1 - ALL_TRUSTED,RP_MATCHES_RCVD scantime=0.2,size=488,user=spamd,uid=58,required_score=5.0,rhost=localhost,radd    r=::1,rport=27779,mid= <20170919113016.34D37115F3A@t7.example.com>,autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no 
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 spamd[572]: prefork: child states: II 
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 postfix/pickup[1189]: 6C0371161CC: uid=58  from=<user1@example.com>
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 postfix/cleanup[1290]: 6C0371161CC: message-id=<20170919113016.34D37115F3A@t7.example.com>
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 postfix/pipe[1310]: 34D37115F3A:  to=<user1@example.com>, relay=spam, delay=0.23, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.2,  dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spam service)
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 postfix/qmgr[1190]: 6C0371161CC: from=<user1@example.com>, size=796, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 postfix/error[1293]: 6C0371161CC: to=<user1@example.com>, relay=none, delay=0, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=4.3.0,  status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
Sep 19 16:00:16 t7 postfix/qmgr[1190]: 34D37115F3A: removed
```

The configs are:
**master.cf**

```
127.0.0.1:10025   inet       n       -    n - -    smtpd
-o mynetworks=192.*.*.*/24
-o content_filter=
-o local_recipient_maps=
-o relay_recipient_maps=
-o  smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
-o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
-o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
-o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
-o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
-o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
-o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
-o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
-o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
-o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
-o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters
-o local_header_rewrite_clients=
-o smtpd_use_tls=no


#SMTP
smtp          inet          n         -          n       -       -          smtpd
-o content_filter=spam:dummy
spam      unix        -       n    n   -   -      pipe
flags=Rq user=spamd argv=/usr/local/bin/spamc -u spamd -e /usr/local /sbin/sendmail -f $sender $recipient
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
-o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRh user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/local/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f  ${sender} -d ${user}@${domain} -m ${extension}
```

Comment: In above code, you have a space in sendmail path (spamd -e /usr/local /sbin/sendmail)

Comment: Sorry, That space is occurred after I copy the code. The source code doesn't have any space.